# Scala shapeless Generic.Aux implicit parameter not found in unapply

Tags: scala, shapeless, unapply

I encountered the following problem with implicits in Scala, using Shapeless's `Generic.Aux`:

```scala
  case class Complex(re: Double, im: Double)

  object Prod2 {
    def unapply[C, A, B](c: C)(implicit C: Generic.Aux[C, A :: B :: HNil]) = Some((C.to(c).head, C.to(c).tail.head))
  }

  val c = Complex(1.0, 2.0)
  val Prod2(re, im) = c
```

The code above does not compile. It reports

```
Error:(22, 7) could not find implicit value for parameter C: shapeless.Generic.Aux[nexus.ops.Test.Complex,A :: B :: shapeless.HNil]
  val Prod2(re, im) = c
Error:(22, 7) not enough arguments for method unapply: (implicit C: shapeless.Generic.Aux[nexus.ops.Test.Complex,A :: B :: shapeless.HNil])Some[(A, B)].
Unspecified value parameter C.
  val Prod2(re, im) = c
```

However, if I manually do

```scala
implicitly[Generic.Aux[Complex, Double :: Double :: HNil]]
```

it is perfectly OK to derive this implicit instance.

Comment: I wouldn't look at this code with two symbols named `C` in scope. Was that intentional?

Comment: Isn't the typeclass instance being the same name as the type the Scala norm? e.g. `K: Eq[K]`

Comment: Maybe I am ignorant about that. I know Scala has bugs about shadowing and implicits, I was supposed to contribute a fix in that area, I may still get around to it.

Comment: @som-snytt Sometimes using the same letter is standard: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Representable.scala#L18 https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/Cokleisli.scala#L167 This depends on code conventions.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works:

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.IsHCons
import shapeless.{::, Generic, HList, HNil}

case class Complex(re: Double, im: Double)

object Prod2 {
  def unapply[C, L <: HList, H, T <: HList, H1, T1 <: HList](c: C)(implicit
    C: Generic.Aux[C, L],
    isHCons: IsHCons.Aux[L, H, T],
    isHCons1: IsHCons.Aux[T, H1, T1]) = Some((C.to(c).head, C.to(c).tail.head))
}

val c = Complex(1.0, 2.0)
val Prod2(re, im) = c
```

Comment: You beat me by a minute, but my answer gives a little more context and (in my view) a slightly better solution, so I'm going to leave it up.

Comment: @TravisBrown It's funny that if we remove `Aux` for 2nd `IsHCons`: `def unapply[C, L <: HList, H, T <: HList](c: C)(implicit
      C: Generic.Aux[C, L],
      isHCons: IsHCons.Aux[L, H, T],
      isHCons1: IsHCons[T]): Option[(H, isHCons1.H)] = ...` then we'll have `error during expansion of this match (this is a scalac bug). The underlying error was: type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: isHCons1.H`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the compiler simply isn't smart enough to perform the unification that would be necessary to infer `A` and `B` here. You can read about some of the details of this problem in section 4.3 of [Underscore's *Type Astronaut’s Guide to Shapeless*](https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html). The book provides a workaround using `IsHCons`, but in this case I think requiring a `<:<` proof is a little cleaner:

```
import shapeless.{::, Generic, HList, HNil}

case class Complex(re: Double, im: Double)

object Prod2 {
  def unapply[C, L <: HList, A, B](c: C)(implicit
    C: Generic.Aux[C, L],
    ev: L <:< (A :: B :: HNil)
  ) = Some((C.to(c).head, C.to(c).tail.head))
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val c = Complex(1.0, 2.0)
c: Complex = Complex(1.0,2.0)

scala> val Prod2(re, im) = c
re: Double = 1.0
im: Double = 2.0
```

It's disappointing, but this is a workaround you'll need over and over if you work with Shapeless, so it's good to have it in your toolbox.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, and also the guide!