# How to implicitly figure out the type at the head of a shapeless HList

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

Lets say I have the following:

```
case class TestField(value: String)
case class TestField2(value: String)

implicit class ProductExtensions[T <: Product](val value T) extends AnyVal {

  def mapTo[R <: Product](implicit tGen: Generic.Aux[T, String :: HNil], rGen: Generic.Aux[R, String :: HNil]: R = ???

}

val testField2 = TestField("my value").mapTo[TestField2]
// TestField2("my value")
```

Can I "genersize" the `mapTo` function to work for types other than `String` without having to specify the type?

Note `TestField` nor `TestField2` implement AnyVal (nor do I want them to), so I can't use `Unwrapped`.

**Edit**

@Dmytro_Mitin answer works in my example above, but if I extend the example to this:

```
implicit class ProductExtensions[T <: Product](val value T) extends AnyVal {

  def mapTo[R <: Product](implicit tGen: Generic.Aux[T, String :: HNil], rGen: Generic.Aux[R, String :: HNil], o: OtherImplicit[String]): R = ???

}
```

...so I am kind of looking for this to work (but it doesn't):

```
implicit class ProductExtensions[T <: Product, U](val value T) extends AnyVal {

  def mapTo[R <: Product](implicit tGen: Generic.Aux[T, U :: HNil], rGen: Generic.Aux[R, U :: HNil], o: OtherImplicit[U]): R = ???

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is generalized version

```
implicit class ProductExtensions[T <: Product, L <: HList](val value: T) extends AnyVal {
  def mapTo[R <: Product](implicit tGen: Generic.Aux[T, L], rGen: Generic.Aux[R, L]): R = rGen.from(tGen.to(value))
}
```

The Type Astronaut’s Guide to Shapeless. 6.3 Case study: case class migrations https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#sec:ops:migration

---

New version

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.IsHCons

implicit class ProductExtensions[T <: Product, L <: HList, U, L1 <: HList](val value: T) extends AnyVal {
  def mapTo[R <: Product](implicit 
                          tGen: Generic.Aux[T, L], 
                          rGen: Generic.Aux[R, L], 
                          isHCons: IsHCons.Aux[L, U, L1], 
                          o: OtherImplicit[U]
                         ): R = rGen.from(tGen.to(value))
}
```

4.3 Chaining dependent functions https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#sec:type-level-programming:chaining

[Scala shapeless Generic.Aux implicit parameter not found in unapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432439/scala-shapeless-generic-aux-implicit-parameter-not-found-in-unapply)

Comment: Ah I tried that but IntelliJ didn't seem to like it...it does compile though!

Comment: @Cheetah Intellij doesnt like a lot of things

Comment: haha - for what its worth, it was fine with the implementation I had...was also fine with using Unwrapped and AnyVal

Comment: @DmytroMitin - I have a similar scenario where I actually need type `L` as `String` (rather than `String :: HNil`) for another implicit - is this possible to get?

Comment: @Cheetah `Generic.Aux[T, String]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DmytroMitin - my comment didn't make sense - I've added to the OP to explain.

Comment: @Cheetah You could read [4.3 Chaining dependent functions](https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#sec:type-level-programming:chaining) about over-constrained implicits.

Comment: That link covered it perfectly. Thank you!